# Adding two vectors (one vectors value change by time)

Tags: vectors

Hi I have two vectors as the image shows below. The red vector has a constant value and is 52.2 (the N is for Newton as you understand) and the other vector has variable value 20+5t (t is for time). I want to add the two vectors and find the measure and the direction of overall vector as function of time...How I can do this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume the other vector has units of $N$ as well. Add normally once you have converted both vectors to components.  For example, the $x$-component of the final result will be $-52.2\sin 17^{\circ} + (20+5t)\cos 54^{\circ}.$ There's nothing special about the situation here.